# If I duplicate an app in /Applications, how can I differentiate it to where both apps show in Launchpad?

Tags: finder, applications, catalina, launchpad

I have run `cp -R /Applications/example1.app /Applications/example2.app` yet only **example1.app** shows in Launchpad. I can see it in Finder as two different apps but not in Launchpad.

Do I need to edit something within the package contents of the app to get it to appear in Launchpad? Permissions?

I am curious as to what MacOS needs to be able to differentiate an application so that it can appear in Finder.

Comment: Have you retartedyour machine since you added the 2nd application?

Comment: @jmh Yes, I have.